# Binding event to a custom wxButton

Tags: c++, events, graphics, wxwidgets

I'm writing an app in C++ wxWidgets. I'm trying to create a custom button class, although there are two problems:

1. I binded a wxEVT_COMMAND_BUTTON_CLICKED to the button to execute a function when it's clicked, but it doesn't seem to get called
2. There's an awful grey border around it, that I'm not being able to remove (not even with wxBORDER_NONE)

[image: My custom buttons]

Code:

gridButton.h

```cpp
#pragma once
#include "wx/wx.h"

enum gbSTYLE {
    NUM,
    OP,
    EXTRA
};

class gridButton : public wxWindow
{
    bool pressed;
    bool hovered;
    wxString text;

    static const int width = 50, height = 50;
    
    wxFont* gbFont = new wxFont(20, wxFONTFAMILY_SWISS, wxFONTSTYLE_NORMAL, 
        wxFONTWEIGHT_LIGHT, false, "Lato");
    // RICORDATI DI CANCELLARE font_Button DALLA CLASSE MAIN QUANDO HAI FINITO

    wxBrush* background;
    wxColour* textColor;

    wxBrush* hoveredBackground;
    wxColour* hoveredTextColor;

    wxBrush* pressedBackground;
    wxColour* pressedTextColor;

public:
    gridButton(wxFrame* parent, wxWindowID id, wxString text, gbSTYLE style);
    ~gridButton();

    void applyStyle(gbSTYLE style);

    void paintEvent(wxPaintEvent& evt);
    void paintNow();
    void render(wxDC& dc);

    void mouseMoved(wxMouseEvent& evt);
    void mouseDown(wxMouseEvent& evt);
    void mouseWheelMoved(wxMouseEvent& evt);
    void mouseReleased(wxMouseEvent& evt);
    void rightClick(wxMouseEvent& evt);
    void mouseLeftWindow(wxMouseEvent& evt);
    void mouseEnterWindow(wxMouseEvent& evt);
    void keyPressed(wxKeyEvent& evt);
    void keyReleased(wxKeyEvent& evt);

    DECLARE_EVENT_TABLE()
};
```

gridButton.cpp

```cpp
#include "gridButton.h"


BEGIN_EVENT_TABLE(gridButton, wxWindow)

    EVT_MOTION(gridButton::mouseMoved)
    EVT_LEFT_DOWN(gridButton::mouseDown)
    EVT_LEFT_UP(gridButton::mouseReleased)
    EVT_RIGHT_DOWN(gridButton::rightClick)
    EVT_ENTER_WINDOW(gridButton::mouseEnterWindow)
    EVT_LEAVE_WINDOW(gridButton::mouseLeftWindow)
    EVT_KEY_DOWN(gridButton::keyPressed)
    EVT_KEY_UP(gridButton::keyReleased)
    EVT_MOUSEWHEEL(gridButton::mouseWheelMoved)

    EVT_PAINT(gridButton::paintEvent)

END_EVENT_TABLE()



// funzione costruttrice (wxFULL_REPAINT_ON_RESIZE per evitare un glitch grafico quando si ridimensiona la finestra)
gridButton::gridButton(wxFrame* parent, wxWindowID id, wxString text, gbSTYLE style)
    : wxWindow(parent, id, wxDefaultPosition, wxDefaultSize, wxFULL_REPAINT_ON_RESIZE) 
{
    SetMinSize(wxSize(width, height));
    this->text = text;
    
    hovered = false;
    pressed = false;

    applyStyle(style);
}

// funzione distruttrice
gridButton::~gridButton()
{
    delete gbFont;

    delete background;
    delete textColor;

    delete hoveredBackground;
    delete hoveredTextColor;

    delete pressedBackground;
    delete pressedTextColor;
}

void gridButton::applyStyle(gbSTYLE style)
{
    switch (style)
    {
    default:
        background = new wxBrush(wxColour(255, 255, 255), wxBRUSHSTYLE_SOLID);
        textColor = new wxColour(25, 25, 25);

        hoveredBackground = new wxBrush(wxColour(125, 125, 125), wxBRUSHSTYLE_SOLID);
        hoveredTextColor = new wxColour(185, 185, 185);

        pressedBackground = new wxBrush(wxColour(25, 25, 25), wxBRUSHSTYLE_SOLID);
        pressedTextColor = new wxColour(200, 200, 200);
        break;

    case NUM:
        background = new wxBrush(wxColour(98, 101, 138), wxBRUSHSTYLE_SOLID);
        textColor = new wxColour(190, 197, 200);

        hoveredBackground = new wxBrush(wxColour(66, 69, 96), wxBRUSHSTYLE_SOLID);
        hoveredTextColor = new wxColour(36, 38, 52);

        pressedBackground = new wxBrush(wxColour(16, 17, 23), wxBRUSHSTYLE_SOLID);
        pressedTextColor = new wxColour(128, 134, 192);
        break;
    }
}


//chiamato da EVT_PAINT ogni frame
void gridButton::paintEvent(wxPaintEvent& evt)
{
    wxPaintDC dc(this);
    render(dc);
}
//eseguire un render quando si vuole
void gridButton::paintNow()
{
    wxClientDC dc(this);
    render(dc);
}

//renderizzazione, qui si mette la grafica
void gridButton::render(wxDC& dc)
{
    int w = this->GetSize().GetWidth();
    int h = this->GetSize().GetHeight();

    if (pressed) {
        dc.SetBrush(*pressedBackground);
        dc.SetTextForeground(*pressedTextColor);
    }
    else if (hovered) {
        dc.SetBrush(*hoveredBackground);
        dc.SetTextForeground(*hoveredTextColor);
    }
    else {
        dc.SetBrush(*background);
        dc.SetTextForeground(*textColor);
    }

    dc.DrawRectangle(0, 0, w, h);

    dc.SetFont(*gbFont);
    wxSize textSize = GetTextExtent(text);
    dc.DrawText(text, w / 2 - (textSize.GetWidth()), h / 2 - (textSize.GetHeight()));
}

void gridButton::mouseDown(wxMouseEvent& evt)
{
    pressed = true;
    paintNow();
}
void gridButton::mouseReleased(wxMouseEvent& evt)
{
    pressed = false;
    paintNow();
}
void gridButton::mouseEnterWindow(wxMouseEvent& evt)
{
    hovered = true;
    paintNow();
}
void gridButton::mouseLeftWindow(wxMouseEvent& evt)
{
    hovered = false;
    pressed = false;
    paintNow();
}

// eventi inutilizzati
void gridButton::mouseMoved(wxMouseEvent& evt) {}
void gridButton::mouseWheelMoved(wxMouseEvent& evt) {}
void gridButton::rightClick(wxMouseEvent& evt) {}
void gridButton::keyPressed(wxKeyEvent& evt) {}
void gridButton::keyReleased(wxKeyEvent& evt) {}
```

This is how I layout the grid (it looks bad right now because I'm still working on the buttons themselves):

```cpp
#include "main.h"


void Main::AddButtons()
{
    int w = 5, h = 4;
    MainGrid = new wxGridSizer(w, h, 0, 0);


        gridButton* test = new gridButton(this, wxID_ANY, "(", NUM);
        MainGrid->Add(test, 0, wxEXPAND);

    AddOpButton(4);

    for (int i = 0; i < 2; i++) MainGrid->AddSpacer(1);

    for (int i = 7; i < 10; i++) AddNumButton(i);
    AddOpButton(3);
    for (int i = 4; i < 7; i++) AddNumButton(i);
    AddOpButton(2);
    for (int i = 1; i < 4; i++) AddNumButton(i);
    AddOpButton(1);
    MainGrid->AddSpacer(1);
    AddNumButton(0);
    
    //dot
    wxButton* dot = new wxButton(this, wxID_ANY, ".");
    dot->SetFont(*font_Button);
    dot->SetBackgroundColour(wxColour(200, 200, 200));
    dot->SetForegroundColour(wxColour(125, 125, 125));
    dot->Bind(wxEVT_COMMAND_BUTTON_CLICKED, &Main::OnDotClicked, this);
    MainGrid->Add(dot, 0, wxEXPAND);

    AddOpButton(0);

    MainSizer->Add(MainGrid, 10, wxEXPAND);
}

void Main::AddNumButton(int n)
{
    gridButton* btn = new gridButton(this, BUTTON_NUM + n, wxString(std::to_string(n)), NUM);
    btn->Bind(wxEVT_COMMAND_BUTTON_CLICKED, &Main::OnNumClicked, this);

    MainGrid->Add(btn, 0, wxEXPAND);
}

void Main::AddOpButton(int n)
{
    std::string s(1, ops[n]);

    gridButton* btn = new gridButton(this, BUTTON_OP + n, wxString(s), OP);
    btn->Bind(wxEVT_COMMAND_BUTTON_CLICKED, &Main::OnOpClicked, this);

    MainGrid->Add(btn, 0, wxEXPAND);
}
```

The events it should trigger:

```cpp
void Main::OnNumClicked(wxCommandEvent& evt)
{
    int id = evt.GetId() - BUTTON_NUM;
    DoNumClick(id);
    evt.Skip();
}

void Main::DoNumClick(int id)
{
    char c = '0' + id;
    char exp[EXPBUFFER];
    strcpy(exp, MainText->GetValue());


    if (strlen(exp) == 1 && exp[0] == '0')
    {
        exp[0] = c;
        MainText->SetLabel(exp);
    }
    else
        MainText->AppendText(std::to_string(id));
}
```

I'm new to wxWidgets and any help is appreciated.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I think the extra grey border is just the extra pixels that are leftover from the grid.  To get rid of the leftover pixels, you can use a flex grid sizer instead and make all the rows and columns flexible.

```
void Main::AddButtons()
{
    MainGrid = new wxFlexGridSizer(w, h, 0, 0);

    for ( int i = 0 ; i < w ; ++ i)
    {
        MainGrid->AddGrowableRow(i);
    }
    for ( int j = 0 ; j < h ; ++j )
    {
        MainGrid->AddGrowableCol(j);
    }
...
```

To get rid of the rectangle around the buttons themselves, instead of drawing a rectangle, you can set a background brush and call the `Clear()` method.  The `Clear()` method completely paints the window with the background brush.

```
void gridButton::render(wxDC& dc)
{
    int w = this->GetSize().GetWidth();
    int h = this->GetSize().GetHeight();

    if (pressed) {
        dc.SetBackground(*pressedBackground);

        dc.SetTextForeground(*pressedTextColor);
    }
    else if (hovered) {
        dc.SetBackground(*hoveredBackground);
        dc.SetTextForeground(*hoveredTextColor);
    }
    else {
        dc.SetBackground(*background);
        dc.SetTextForeground(*textColor);
    }

    dc.Clear();
```

The border you were seeing before was do to the edges of the rectangles being drawn with the default pen.

I have one small recommendation.  I would store the colors instead of the brushes themselves.  Each brush is a gdi object and on windows there's a limit to the number of [gdi objects available](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/win32/sysinfo/gdi-objects).

For example, if you have stored the pressedBackgroundColor, you can create a brush on the stack like this:

```
    if (pressed) {
        wxBrush temp(*pressedBackgroundColor));
        dc.SetBackground(temp);
```

or you can let the brush be created implicitly like this:

```
    if (pressed) {
        dc.SetBackground(*pressedBackgroundColor);
```

This is admittedly a slight deoptimization since brushes have to be created in each call to the `render` method.  So feel free to ignore this if you aren't concerned about the gdi limit on windows.

---

To answer the first question.  You'll need to manually generate the button press for your custom button.  The easiest way to do this is in the `mouseReleased` method.  To generate the button event, the method needs do something like this:

```
void gridButton::mouseReleased(wxMouseEvent& evt)
{
    pressed = false;
    paintNow();

    // Create a button event and send it for processing.
    wxCommandEvent event(wxEVT_BUTTON);
    event.SetId(GetId());
    event.SetEventObject(this);
    // Set any other data needed here.

    ProcessWindowEvent(event);
}
```

In order to avoid confusion with native buttons, you can also create your own event types with the `wxDECLARE_EVENT` and `wxDEFINE_EVENT` [macros](https://docs.wxwidgets.org/trunk/group__group__funcmacro__events.html#ga767b12d37f7370bc5f6b3d62340f3ef8). There is more detail in the [documentation](https://docs.wxwidgets.org/trunk/overview_events.html#overview_events_custom).

Comment: Thank you, I'll try that out later and tell you if it works. By the way, I edited the post so you can see the code I used to layout the grid.

Comment: Ok, I just tested your code and it works wonders, thanks. Hope someone can help me with the other one as well.

Comment: Does using a flex grid sizer instead of grid sizer get rid of the grey border?

Comment: Nope. I've tried [changing wxGridSizer to wxFlexGridSizer and adding flexible rows and columns the way you said](https://pasteboard.co/K3NrEJO.png), and [this is the result I get.](https://pasteboard.co/K3NqkdQ.png)

Comment: I don't think I understand.  Is something like [this](https://imgur.com/a/4bTclEW) what you're trying to create (with no borders around the buttons at all)?  If not, they I'm not sure what border you are trying to get rid of.

Comment: Exactly, they are the borders I'm trying to get rid of.

Comment: That's what I'm trying to create

Comment: I made an edit above that should show how to change the render method to get rid of those lines.

Comment: It worked, thank you so much! And thank you also for the tip, I didn't know about that.