# wxWidgets GridSizer puts all buttons in the same position

Tags: c++, wxwidgets

I'm learning wxWidgets and am trying to make minesweeper using `wxButton`s. I use the following code to create and position the buttons:

```
int length = 10;

wxGridSizer *grid = new wxGridSizer(length, length, 0, 0);
wxButton *buttons[length*length];

for (int i=0; i<length*length; i++){
    buttons[i] = new wxButton(this, wxID_ANY);
    grid->Add(buttons[i], 1, wxEXPAND | wxALL);
    if (mineField[i]){
        Bind(wxEVT_BUTTON, &MainWindow::isMine, this);
    } else {
        Bind(wxEVT_BUTTON, &MainWindow::notMine, this);
    }
    
}
```

I expect this to generate a 10x10 grid of buttons, but instead it positions all of the buttons at (0,0). I have been Googling the problem for a while now but I can't find the issue. How do I position the buttons in a 10x10 grid? Thanks.

Comment: you should call `Layout()` at the end.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

To make the grid sizer layout the buttons, you need to either

1. set it to be the sizer for a window or
2. add it to another sizer.

Assuming the code above is from the constructor of your main frame window, you would set grid to be the sizer for the frame like this

```
SetSizer(grid);
```

On the other hand, if you have other controls in the frame and need to add grid to another sizer, you could do that something like this:

```
otherSizer->Add(grid,wxSizerFlags(0));
```

Obviously, 'otherSizer' should be replaced with the name of the other sizer.  There are many [options that can be used with wxSizerFlags](https://docs.wxwidgets.org/trunk/classwx_sizer_flags.html) to get the exact layout you want.

In addition, as mentioned above, it's sometimes helpful to end all the code the creates and organizes the controls your using with a call to the `Layout()` method.

---

Another tactic you can use is to have a single panel be the only child of the frame and then set a sizer for the panel.  This works because in wxWidgets whenever a top level window such as a frame has a single child, that child is automatically sized to fill all of the available area.

Using this technique, a layout with a text control along the top and the grid underneath it could be created like this:

```
// Create the controls
wxPanel* bgPanel = new wxPanel(this, wxID_ANY);
wxTextCtrl* text = new wxTextCtrl(bgPanel, wxID_ANY);

wxGridSizer *grid = new wxGridSizer(length, length, 0, 0);
wxButton *buttons[length*length];

for (int i=0; i<length*length; i++){
    buttons[i] = new wxButton(bgPanel, wxID_ANY);
    grid->Add(buttons[i], 1, wxEXPAND | wxALL);
    if (mineField[i]){
        Bind(wxEVT_BUTTON, &MainWindow::isMine, this);
    } else {
        Bind(wxEVT_BUTTON, &MainWindow::notMine, this);
    }

}

// Create a sizer for the panel and add the text control and grid to it.
wxBoxSizer* mainSizer = new wxBoxSizer(wxVERTICAL);
mainSizer->Add(text, wxSizerFlags(0).Expand().Border(wxALL));
mainSizer->Add(grid,wxSizerFlags(1).Expand().Border(wxLEFT|wxRIGHT|wxBOTTOM));
bgPanel->SetSizer(mainSizer);
```

Comment: What if I have multiple sizers in a frame? Can I do that? I want to have a text box that spans the whole width at the top of the frame and have the rest of the frame filled with buttons in a grid. If I use SetSizer then I can't have both sizers, right?

Comment: I've added to the answer to show how to put both the text control and the grid of buttons in a sizer.  I also added a panel to the frame to serve as the parent for the text control and the buttons - otherwise the frame has an ugly grey background.

Comment: Another suggestion I would make is to use a flex grid sizer instead of a grid sizer as I [suggested in the first part of this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/67707070/6846682).  That way the grid will take up all of the space.  With the simple grid sizer, any pixels that cant be assigned evenly to the grid will be left empty.

Comment: @NewPagodi, (s)he still will need to call Layout() though...